# Print out each result in a for loop as a table with each iteration and result displayed

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I want to basically print out the results for name, surname, age and salary under each other as a form of a table under the titles Name, Surname, Age, Salary. The way it is getting outputted at the moment is just wrong. Any tips on what I should do are greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[20], surname[20];
    int age, salary;


    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; ++i) {
        printf("Insert name:");
        scanf("%s", name);
        printf("Insert surname:");
        scanf("%s", surname);
        printf("Insert age:");
        scanf("%d", &age);
        printf("Insert salary:");
        scanf("%d", &salary);

            for (int i = 1; i <= 2; ++i) {
               printf("%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\t", name, surname, age, salary);

        }
    }

    printf("Name\tSurname\tAge\tSalary\t\n");
    printf("%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\t", name, surname, age, salary);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%-19.19s\t%-19.19s\t%6d\t%6d\n", name, surname, age, salary);` , notice the max length specifier and the line break at the end

Comment: Or, avoid the use of `tabs` completely and just add `8` to each of the *field-width* modifiers where required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to basically print out the results for name, surname, age and
>   salary under each other as a form of a table under the titles Name,
>   Surname, Age, Salary.

Just use `printf("Name\tSurname\tAge\tSalary\t\n");` before printing the result and also use `'\n'` to print the result in a new line.

```
printf("Name\tSurname\tAge\tSalary\t\n");
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; ++i) {
   printf("%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\t\n", name, surname, age, salary);}
```

Edited:

Use `Array of Structure` to store data of multiple employees.
First store the data and then print the result using `loop`.

Here is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct employee{  //<-----define the structure 
 int age, salary;
 char name[20];
 char surname[20];

};

int main()
{
    struct employee em[3]; //<----create an array of employee


    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; ++i) {  //<----take the data from user
        printf("Insert name:");
        scanf("%s", em[i-1].name);
        printf("Insert surname:");
        scanf("%s", em[i-1].surname);
        printf("Insert age:");
        scanf("%d", &em[i-1].age);
        printf("Insert salary:");
        scanf("%d", &em[i-1].salary);



        }

        printf("Name\tSurname\tAge\tSalary\t\n");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; ++i) {  //<---print the data 

               printf("%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\t\n", em[i-1].name, em[i-1].surname, em[i-1].age, em[i-1].salary);
        }
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: This will however print each result twice. What I want is first the program executes the block of commands for the user to enter all the names surnames etc he wants THEN all the results will be displayed

Comment: @DavidVella I have edited my answer. Hope it will give you the desired result.

Comment: @suvojit_007 please, do not spoon-feed and at least let the OP edit the question. On the other hand, if you are using `i-1` in the subset, `em[2]` is enough.

Comment: @suvojit_007 thanks a lot! I'm new to this and didn't know how to explain it

Comment: @KeineLust You are correct. I had to edit my answer because I didn't get his question from the post.

Comment: @suvojit_007 One more thing ... if i would want to add another column and call it Total which calculates the Salary of each individual multiplied by 12. How would I go about this?

Thanks again

Comment: @DavidVella simply create another field `Total` in the structure